# Могу ли я в конструкторе делать вычисления?

Tags: java, наследование, конструктор, переопределение

У меня есть класс Figure, который описывает площадь и периметр. У меня есть также множество фигур, унаследованных от этого класса. Как я могу задать для каждой фигуры определение площади и периметра? Можно это делать в конструкторе (как я и сделал) или же необходимо переопределять сеттер родителя? Или вообще иначе как-то я должен сделать? Подскажите пожалуйста. Заранее спасибо

Вот класс родитель для всех фигур:

```
public class Figure {
    private double area;
    private double perimeter;

    public double getArea() {
        return area;
    }

    public void setArea(double area) {
        this.area = area;
    }

    public double getPerimeter() {
        return perimeter;
    }

    public void setPerimeter(double perimeter) {
        this.perimeter = perimeter;
    }
}
```

Вот мой круг:

```
public class Cirlce extends Figure {
    private double radius;

    public Cirlce(double radius) {
        this.radius = radius;
        super.setArea(radius*2*Math.PI);
    }
}
```

Comment: Я так понимаю, объекты могут быть изменяемые ? Или нет ? Как хотите реализовать ?

Comment: Вопрос о том, можно ли так сделать...или вопрос о целесообразности такого подхода?

Comment: @Gin Tasan да, объекты могут быть изменяемые

Comment: @Виталий Шебаниц и то и то)

Comment: если площадь у всех считается одинаково, то да

Comment: @michael_best к сожалению, у всех фигур площадь считается по-разному)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Класс Circle:

UPD:Код был переделан,по желанию автора, теперь переменные класса Figure нельзя изменять, задаются один раз при создании

В конструкторе лучше не помещать какие либо вычисления, ибо там могут быть викунуты различные исключения, так же лучшек не помещать туда методов, так как вызов некоторых методов, в которых , например, могут быть заранее не определены или не инициализированы какие либо переменные.
Однако, метод может быть вызван, если вы на 100% знаете, что там не будет описаных выше проблем. Такой метод желательно должен только определять объект, и манипулировать только переменными, которые он получает, иначе, как говорил раннее , может быть проблема. В mathArea() и mathPerimeter() необходимо будет создать обработку исключений. Есть так называемый public static метод, в который передается значение радиуса, и если оно не соблюдает условия, объект не создается, без этого метода в конструкторе, в методе setRadius(..); при передачи отрицательного значения объект бы был СОЗДАН, и возвращал бы дэфолтные значения double area и parameter, что не допустимо. Есть исключение NullPointerException при попытке создать и изменить объект , как показано в qew.java , и необходимо для каждой фигуры устанавливать индивидуальную обработку исключений в методах, при создании и тд, где это собственно возможно. Так же есть другие плюсы такой архитектуры, если интересно какие , отпишите

```
        public class Circle extends Figure {
    private double radius;

    public static Circle createCircle(double radius)
    {
        if(radius <= 0) {System.out.println("WHY ? Stop it...");return null;} else return new Circle(radius);
    }
    public Circle(double radius) {
        setRadius(radius);
    }

    private double mathArea()
    {
        return Math.pow(radius,2)*Math.PI;
    }
     private double mathPerimeter()
    {
        return 2*radius*Math.PI;
    }
    private void setRadius(double radius){
        this.radius = radius;
        super.setPerimeter(mathPerimeter());
        super.setArea(mathArea());
            }
}
```

Класс qew.java , у меня с main методом: Тест, попытка создать объект, с отрицательным радиусом.

```
public class qew {
public static void main(String[] args) {
Circle c = Circle.createCircle(4);
System.out.println(c.getArea());
System.out.println(c.getPerimeter());
}
}
```

Класс Figure: Класс абстрактный, ибо зачем нужны его экземпляры, он должен предоставлять ОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНЫЕ переменные, которые 100% будут использованы для его потомков, иначе, нужно определить их в классах - потомках. К методам это относится так же.

```
    abstract public class Figure {
    private double area;
    private double perimeter;

    public double getArea() {
        return area;
    }

    public void setArea(double area){
    this.area = area;
    };

    public double getPerimeter() {
        return perimeter;
    }
    public void setPerimeter(double perimeter){
    this.perimeter = perimeter;
    };
}
```

Comment: я может чего-то не понимаю или некорректно задаю вопрос, но: у нас есть класс Figure, в нём объявлены параметры double area и double perimeter. Я хочу чтобы в нём был какой-то метод, записывающий в эти параметры значение и чтобы этот метод был переопределен в каждом последующем классе уже конкретной фигуры. И ещё мне кажется, что не стоит делать проверку на setRadius - он будет вводиться один раз, при создании объекта и после этого изменяться уже не будет. Метода set не будет в каждой фигуре отдельно

Comment: @ВладиславЭстрин , 1 - вы сказали, что объекты будут изменяемые, так как они изменяемые, можно менять значения переменных в них, поэтому был предложен такой вариант, 2 - Если вы переопределите метод, который записывает значения, например, setArea(), например, в  классе Circle, то вы не сможете установить значение area в классе Figure, так как оно private, а, если сделаете их protected, смысл тогда их иметь их в классе Figure  ? Это нецелесообразно(еще по некоторым причинам). Однако, вы сможете записать эти значения, если в классе наследнике(Circle), вызовите метод класса Figure

Comment: я прошу прощения, что ввел в заблуждение Вас. Как в итоге правильнее всего будет сделать? Эта реализация вообще является частью большой задачи https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FjSOE2QHqfOB8u_BPMN-Z1ky00_R3g7v/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @ВладиславЭстрин , и хотел спросить, что имеете ввиду под проверкой setRadius ? Метод createCircle() сделан для того, что бы если пользователь ввел некорректное число, объект не создавался и память не ушла впустую. А если объект только один раз создается, тогда сейчас код обновлю

Comment: хочу ещё такой вопрос задать: есть ли смысл вообще в классе Figure? Если мы не переопределяем его методы, а просто создаем в каждом классе отдельно методы для вычисления площади и периметра, так может проще в том же классе создавать и параметры площадь и периметр, определяя их в конструкторе сразу же? Совсем запутался я)

Comment: @ВладиславЭстрин , Тут работает механизм наследования - один из мощнейших языковых инструментов. Он создан отчасти для упрощения взаимодействия. Вы используете у класса Figure методы getArea() getParameter() , так же, не заморачиваетесь в каждом классе с очередным созданием одинаковых некоторых методов и переменных, а так же их переопределением, так же этот вариант с наследованием, не так уж и плох , можете попробовать вариант с композицией. Код я обновил

Comment: Вообще, можете почитать литературу по правильному использованию конструкций языка, и узнать о каждой мелочи, а там поймете где и как ее лучше использовать(операторы и тд, всякие тонкие мелочи, которые было бы полезно знать есть на всяких сайтах с вопросами аля "Собеседование java " и тд, удачи :)  https://jsehelper.blogspot.com/2016/01/blog-post_59.html)

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: @ВладиславЭстрин, обращайтесь и удачи в разработке

Comment: ещё такой вопрос: а могли бы мы это реализовать с помощью интерфейсов и есть ли в этом смысл?

Comment: @ВладиславЭстрин , интерфейс , который реализуют классы как Circle и т.д. - не оптимально - много проблем с написанием одинакового кода, в итоге путаница. Можете реализовать интерфейс с помощью класса Figure, если вы уверены, что работа интерфейса подойдет для дальнейшей работы со всем остальным.(Этот вариант подходит, если вы уверены, что вам точно нужен функционал именно интерфейса, хотя у вас уже есть абстрактный класс Figure, так что особого смысла я не вижу), а так, реализация с абстрактным классом Figure довольно таки не плохой вариант

Comment: обнаружил одну неприятность. при создании экземпляра circle мы можем вызвать метод circle.setArea(999) и испортить реальную его площадь)

Comment: @ВладиславЭстрин , извиняюсь, видимо забегался, отпишу, когда обновлю код, когда будет время

Comment: @ВладиславЭстрин Извиняюсь, что так долго, решение все еще актуально ?

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете создать абстрактный класс Figure и в нем задать поля "площадь" и "периметр". А потом создать абстрактные методы getPerimetr и getArea и в каждом классе который наследуется от фигуры переопределять их.

```
public abstract class Figure {
    private double area;
    private double perimeter;

    public double getArea();

    public double getPerimeter();
}

public class Cirlce extends Figure {
    private double radius;

    public Cirlce(double radius) {
        this.radius = radius;
    }

    @Override
    public double getArea(){
        return radius*radius*Math.PI;

    @Override
    public double getPerimeter(){
        return radius*2*Math.PI;
    } 

}

public class Rectangle extends Figure {
    private double length;
    private double width;

    public Rectangle(double length, double width) {
        this.length = length;
        this.width = width;
    }

    @Override
    public double getArea(){
        return length*width;

    @Override
    public double getPerimeter(){
        return 2*(length*width);
    } 

}
```

А вычислять в конструкторе ничего не стоит

Comment: а зачем тогда параметры double area и double perimeter в классе Fugure?

Comment: Потому что площадь и периметр есть у всех фигур.

Comment: так мы ведь нигде не ссылаемся на эти параметры, ничего в них на записываем

Comment: public double getArea(); эта запись неправильная, либо метод должен быть абстрактным. А если он абстрактный, то переопределить его не получится. Вы написали какую-то ерунду в общем